# Augmentation of a path using awk and/or sed commands

Tags: awk, sed

I'm an awk and sed newbie. I have the following string in a file

```
mount --bind /vsepr_app_repo/fedora/20/plone/4.3.4/Plone/buildout-cache/downloads /buildout-cache/downloads
```

and I want to produce the following output from it:

```
mount --bind /vsepr_app_repo/fedora/20/plone/4.3.4/Plone/buildout-cache/downloads /Plone/buildout-cache/downloads
```

How can I do that using sed and awk commands in a shell script?
I want to repeat the same operations on many lines of my file.
Any suggestion would help me a lot.

Comment: remove all the `>` symbols at the start.

Comment: be a little more explicit about what you want. Is it the addition of the word `Plone`, the word at this place ? on each line of a file or just on this exactly the same, ... that will change lot of thing.

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing a few more details, the following awk command is a start.

```
$ cat data
mount --bind /vsepr_app_repo/fedora/20/plone/4.3.4/Plone/buildout-cache/downloads /buildout-cache/downloads
$ awk '/^mount.*buildout-cache.downloads/ { $NF = "/Plone" $NF; print }' < data
mount --bind /vsepr_app_repo/fedora/20/plone/4.3.4/Plone/buildout-cache/downloads /Plone/buildout-cache/downloads
```

It will prefix the last token on the line with `/Plone` for any lines that start with `mount` and end with `buildout-cache/downloads`.

The `/^mount.*buildout-cache.downloads/` part makes the block apply to lines that match the regular expression.  The command block uses `$NF` which is a reference to the last field on the line, prepends it with `"/Plone"`, and then prints the entire line out.

Answer (score 0):

for the generic folder name in path

```
sed 's#\(/[^/]\{1,\}\)\(/.\{1,\}\)\([[:space:]]\{1,\}\)\2$#\1\2\3\1\2#' YourFile
```

based on last path as pattern on first path